Pycharm 'Hangul' Encoding issue
import os
os.system("dir")

this prints below...
C:\Users\mypbs\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.1\scratches ���͸�

2024-12-23  ���� 12:55    <DIR>          . 
2024-12-23  ���� 12:55    <DIR>          .. 
2021-05-12  ���� 11:06               320 1_html.html 
2021-05-12  ���� 11:09                66 1_html.py 
2024-12-19  ���� 01:45               310 245page_algorithm.py 
2024-12-19  ���� 02:09                28 basic.txt 
2023-11-16  ���� 05:51               330 eng_slice.py 
2024-12-19  ���� 02:32               744 file_read_randomnumbers.py 
2024-12-19  ���� 02:33               619 file_write_randomnumbers.py 
2024-12-19  ���� 02:33            17,000 info.txt 
2023-01-06  ���� 12:27               462 Learning.html 
2023-11-24  ���� 01:38                50 main.py 
2024-12-23  ���� 12:30               398 module_sys.py 
2023-11-24  ���� 12:51               294 movie_name.txt 
2023-11-16  ���� 10:16               428 numpy_practice.py 
2024-12-23  ���� 12:27               978 random module.py 
2021-05-23  ���� 01:34               196 scratch.html 
2022-12-24  ���� 09:27               875 scratch.py 
2024-12-23  ���� 12:55               649 scratch_1.py 
2023-11-13  ���� 10:59               849 scratch_2.py 
2023-11-17  ���� 02:26             1,660 scratch_4.py 
2023-11-17  ���� 03:40               937 scratch_5.py 
2024-12-21  ���� 11:48                11 test_file.txt 
2021-05-12  ���� 11:17               579 xpath.txt 
2023-11-14  ���� 01:33             4,977 ���Ǳ�_v1.05.py

I've changed settings utf-8 to print 'hangul-korean character' but it doesn't work at all. could you give me some advice? thanks.


Please [edit] your question and format it properly. Run from an open command prompt window dir. Is there any difference if you run python -c "import os;os.system('dir')"?

hello, i'm not good at use text editor in stackoverflow, i don't know how to edit my question code properly, sorry.

i've just typed your code {python -c "import os;os.system('dir')"} and it works well in windows command line, but pycharm doesn't show 'hangul character'

Please check Terminal character encoding inside Advanced settings
